# Which framework for calling server?

Tags: configuration, anonymity

I need to develop a tor-compatible site and one of the requirements is not to use `javascript`. Which framework are people using? I'm not a `php` developer so that won't be a good option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real consensus on frameworks that people are using except being based on LAMP/LEMP. A good rule of thumb is that the more complex a site, the more possible it is  to get hacked or to be de-anonymized.

Some options to look at:

- Conversion to HTML from Asciidoc/Markdown
- Hugo
- Direct HTML with an editor

All of these can create nice looking yet simple websites. If you are looking for something more complex such as applications written in Ruby/Rails, then you might want to check with the tor-onions mailing list to see if what frameworks that people are using and what safety concerns do you need to be aware of.

One final thing, think about what you want to do with your onion service. Is it a blog or purely information? If so, maybe plain html is the way to go. Is it meant to be shiny and interactive? Then you will want to plan specifically what it should be able to do, what language/framework is best to do it, and what security requirements are needed.